# What is the difference between pd.ArrowDtype(pa.string()) and pd.StringDtype("pyarrow")?

Tags: pandas, string, types, pyarrow, apache-arrow

From here we can read: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/pyarrow.html

> The string alias "string[pyarrow]" maps to pd.StringDtype("pyarrow") which is not equivalent to specifying dtype=pd.ArrowDtype(pa.string()). Generally, operations on the data will behave similarly except pd.StringDtype("pyarrow") can return NumPy-backed nullable types while pd.ArrowDtype(pa.string()) will return ArrowDtype.

But they don't say what is the motivation behind these two different types, or how to convert them. Specially when it seems they have slightly different behaviors:

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pandas as pd
a = pd.Series(["tsht(thsat","gda(gr"], dtype="string[pyarrow]").str.split("(").str[0]
b = pd.Series(["tsht(thsat","gda(gr"], dtype=pd.ArrowDtype(pa.string())).str.split("(").str[0]
```

The first succeed, but the second fails!

I could solve it like this:

```
if b.dtype == "string[pyarrow]":
     b = a.astype("string[pyarrow]")
```

But In my opinion this code looks quite ridiculous, as it is read as you are not doing anything and still solves the issue like magic.

Just wanted to known the motivation of having these two data types? And if there is any more elegant way of treating this kind of issue.

In reality I get the "pd.ArrowDtype(pa.string())" type from pd.read_excel so i can not pretend it doesn't exist as it is really breaking code when passing the type to arrow.